# How to handle exceptions in Next.js 13 using middleware?

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to handle exceptions in Next.js 13 using middleware, but my code doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's what I have so far:

```
import { NextRequest, NextFetchEvent, NextResponse } from "next/server"

export function middleware(req: NextRequest, event: NextFetchEvent) {
    try {
        return NextResponse.next()
    } catch (error: Error | any) {
        return NextResponse.json({
            error: {
                message: error.message,
                status: error.status,
            }
        })
    }
}
```

When an exception occurs, I expect the middleware to catch it and return a JSON response with the error details. However, the code above doesn't seem to be doing that. Instead, it just returns a 500 status error as an exception thrown elsewhere in the app causes it to crash.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to handle exceptions in Next.js 13 using middleware? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The current `Next.js` middleware feature works with incoming network requests. It can handle transformations that apply to all routes in your application, but it won't handle errors occurring outside of the `request/response` lifecycle.

The try-catch block in your middleware function is effectively just surrounding the `NextResponse.next()` statement. If an exception occurs elsewhere in your application, **it won't be caught by this block**.

Here are some discussions around this topic on `Next.js` GitHub discussions:

1- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17832

2- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/32230

As per the current state of affairs, it might be best to implement error handling within each part of your application separately. This could be within React components (possibly using `error boundaries`), API routes (with try-catch blocks), or even consider using third-party error tracking services like `@sentry/nextjs` for a more centralized error logging.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same limitation recently with the new Next.js middleware and global error handling for API routes.

I ended up creating the below custom `apiHandler` wrapper for both global middleware and exception handling:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

import { errorHandler, jwtMiddleware, validateMiddleware } from './';

export { apiHandler };

function apiHandler(handler: any) {
    const wrappedHandler: any = {};
    const httpMethods = ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'];

    // wrap handler methods to add middleware and global error handler
    httpMethods.forEach(method => {
        if (typeof handler[method] !== 'function')
            return;

        wrappedHandler[method] = async (req: NextRequest, ...args: any) => {
            try {
                // monkey patch req.json() because it can only be called once
                const json = await req.json();
                req.json = () => json;
            } catch {}

            try {
                // global middleware
                await jwtMiddleware(req);
                await validateMiddleware(req, handler[method].schema);

                // route handler
                const responseBody = await handler[method](req, ...args);
                return NextResponse.json(responseBody || {});
            } catch (err: any) {
                // global error handler
                return errorHandler(err);
            }
        };
    });

    return wrappedHandler;
}
```

And here's an example API route (`/api/account/login`) that uses the `apiHandler`:

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import joi from 'joi';

import { usersRepo } from '_helpers/server';
import { apiHandler } from '_helpers/server/api';

module.exports = apiHandler({
    POST: login
});

async function login(req: Request) {
    const body = await req.json();
    const { user, token } = await usersRepo.authenticate(body);

    // return jwt token in http only cookie
    cookies().set('authorization', token, { httpOnly: true });

    return user;
}

login.schema = joi.object({
    username: joi.string().required(),
    password: joi.string().required()
});
```

The complete project is available at https://jasonwatmore.com/next-js-13-app-router-mongodb-user-rego-and-login-tutorial-with-example

Answer (score 0):

The error handling for the Edge middleware is restricted by the [standard Web API](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/edge) which has limited error handling options. Using `NextResponse.error()` results in a promise reject for the fetch request and renders the not-found page.

My workaround is based on `Response.rewrite` by a middleware exception handler that redirects to an error page. The middleware logic calls the exception handler e.g. with 401. Secondly the exception handler is called in case the next-connect Edge router promise is rejected.

```
export async function exceptionHandler(req: NextRequest, status: number, message?: string) {
    const base64 = btoa(JSON.stringify({ succes: false, status, message }));
    const rewrite = new URL(`/error/${base64}`, req.url);
    return NextResponse.rewrite(rewrite);
}
```

The client renders the error page `/error/[base64]/page.tsx`.

```
'use server';

export default async function Error({ params }) {
    const decoded = decodeURIComponent(params.base64);
    const error = JSON.parse(atob(decoded));

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{error.status}</h2>
            <span>{error.message}</span>
        </div>
    );
}
```